# Titan db 1.0 : Tinkerpop3 Getting Index WARNING after querying geo Predicate

Tags: graph-databases, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I'm using titan 1.0 db with GEO Predicate based on external index (elasticsearch):
as I know there are 3 possibilities: DISJOINT ,WITHIN,INTERSECT.

when I executing WITHIN/geoWithin no WARNING appears

```
 g.V().has(STORY_LOCATION, geoWithin(circle));
```

but when call GEO DISJOINT:

```
 g.V().has(STORY_LOCATION, geoDisjoint(circle));
```

I'm getting Index WARNING

```
WARNING: Query requires iterating over all vertices [(storyLocation disjoint circle[30.0,30.0]:5000.0)]. For better performance, use indexes
```

I'm trying to understand what are the differences between geoWithin vs geoDisjoint regarding indexes issues..

```
P.S:
index configuration:
 PropertyKey storyLocation = createPropertyKey(tm, STORY_LOCATION, Geoshape.class, Cardinality.SINGLE);

tm.buildIndex(indexName, TitanVertex.class).addKey(storyLocation).buildMixedIndex("search")
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `geoWithin` is the only predicate that can make use of an index, all others are full scans. I guess this is a technical limitation dictated by the search backend.